# How it is possible to initialize an array in this form with null values? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

How it is possible to initialize an array in this form with null values in Java?

```
int array[][] = {
            {1, 6, 4, 1,-1},
            {6, 3, 3, 3, 9},
            {6, 3, 3, 3, 9},
            {6, 3, 3, 3, 9},
            {6, 3, 3, 3, 9}
    };
```

I tried that, but it doesn't work (is that possible?):

```
int array[][] = {
            {1, 6, 4, 1,-1},
            {6, null, 3, 3, 9},
            {6, 3, 3, 3, 9},
            {6, 3, 3, null, 9},
            {6, 3, 3, 3, 9}
    };
```

Thanks

Comment: Primitives can't be set as `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only possible with arrays of reference types :

```
Integer array[][] = {
        {1, 6, 4, 1,-1},
        {6, null, 3, 3, 9},
        {6, 3, 3, 3, 9},
        {6, 3, 3, null, 9},
        {6, 3, 3, 3, 9}
};
```

Primitive types can't be assigned `null`, so primitive arrays, such as `int` arrays, can't contain `null`s.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfect!